# Compare to arrays and display the matching values in table in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, loops

`I have two objects of arrays and need to compare both the arrays and display the matching values in table format, I have tried by looping the both arrays and compared them with Id and here matched three of them but when I am trying to display those value in table but getting only one value

Any ideas on what's wrong here...?`your text`

```
 ar1 = [
    { id: 1, itemId: 'html' },
    { id: 2, itemId: 'css' },
    { id: 3, itemId: 'JavaScript' },
  ];


 ar2 = [
     {id:4, itemId:'function'}
    { id: 3, itemId: 'Array' },
    { id: 2, itemId: 'classes' },
    { id: 1, itemId: 'tag' },
  ];



  this.ar1.forEach((array1Item: any, i: any) => {
      this.ar2.forEach((array2Item: any, j: any) => {
        if (array1Item.id === array2Item.id) {
        
          this.matchedValues= array2Item.itemId;
        }
      });
    });



<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Tech</th>
      <th>Key Words</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let tech of ar1">
      <td>
        {{ data.id }}
      </td>
      <td>{{ tech.itemId }}</td>
      <td>{{ matchedValues}}</td>
    </tr>
  </toddy>
</table>

results:

id   tech         keyword
1    HTML          Array
2    Css           Array
3    JavasCript    Array

results want:

id   tech         keyword
1    HTML          Tag
2    CSS           Classes
3    JavaScript    Array`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `forEach` to this and it should work.

```js
const ar1 = [
    { id: 1, itemId: 'html' },
    { id: 2, itemId: 'css' },
    { id: 3, itemId: 'JavaScript' },
];


const ar2 = [
    { id: 4, itemId: 'function' },
    { id: 3, itemId: 'Array' },
    { id: 2, itemId: 'classes' },
    { id: 1, itemId: 'tag' },
];

ar1.forEach(a1 => {
    a1.matchedValues = ar2.find(a2 => a2.id === a1.id).itemId;
});

console.log(ar1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ar1 = [
    { id: 1, itemId: "html" },
    { id: 2, itemId: "css" },
    { id: 3, itemId: "JavaScript" },
];

const ar2 = [
    { id: 4, itemId: "function" },
    { id: 3, itemId: "Array" },
    { id: 2, itemId: "classes" },
    { id: 1, itemId: "tag" },
];

const nwMap = new Map();
for (const item of ar2) nwMap.set(item.id, item.itemId);

const matchedArray = ar1.map((el, i) => ({ ...el, matchedValues: nwMap.get(el.id) }));
console.log(matchedArray);
```

Comment: Please add some comments as to what you did and why

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ar1 = [
    { id: 1, itemId: 'html' },
    { id: 2, itemId: 'css' },
    { id: 3, itemId: 'JavaScript' },
];


const ar2 = [
    { id: 4, itemId: 'function' },
    { id: 3, itemId: 'Array' },
    { id: 2, itemId: 'classes' },
    { id: 1, itemId: 'tag' },
];

const matchedItems = [];
for (const a of ar1) {
    const id = a.id
    const fiter =  ar2.find(x => x.id === id);
    matchedItems.push({
        ...a,
        keyword: fiter.itemId
    })
}

console.log(matchedItems)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).